# Error: Cannot read property '' of undefined when I get return off subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-web-api

[image]I'm calling an api that returns a json, I get this json and display on the console normally, but when I try to assign an object I get error.

Cannot read property '' of undefined.

service :

```
      BuscarUsuarioPorId(id): Observable<Usuario>
 {
   debugger
    let urlPrefix = this.url + '/Usuario/GetUsuarioPorId/' + id;


    return this.http.get(urlPrefix, this.options )
    .map((res: Response) => res.json()).catch(err => Observable.throw(this.handleError(err)))
  }
```

Component:

```
      id: number;
  private usuario: Usuario;
  private turnos: Turno[];
  private nivelAcessoList: NivelAcesso[];
  nome: string;

  constructor(
    private _usuarioServico: UsuariosService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    debugger
    this._usuarioServico
      .ListarTurnos()
      .subscribe(resp => this.turnos = resp);

    this._usuarioServico
      .ListarNivelAcesso()
      .subscribe(resp => this.nivelAcessoList = resp);
    this.GetUsuarioById();
    this.nome = this.usuario.nm_Usuario;

  }

  GetUsuarioById()
  {
   return this._usuarioServico
      .BuscarUsuarioPorId(this.id)
      .subscribe(resp =>  {
       this.usuario = resp;
       console.log(this.usuario);
      });

  }
```

Comment: Your code cannot guarantee 'this.usuario' assigned first as both methods are asynchronized. You need to queue them one after one's dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript and with it Typescript is async by nature. Read a bit about it. This means that the subscription in `GetUsuarioById` won't be called before you want to assign `this.nome`. To get what you want move that assignment into the `GetUsuarioById` call:

```
GetUsuarioById() {
 return this._usuarioServico
  .BuscarUsuarioPorId(this.id)
  .subscribe(resp =>  {
   this.usuario = resp;
   this.nome = this.usuario.nm_Usuario;
  });
}
```